# How to see the full filename of an attachment in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, attachments

Outlook 2016 handles attachments a little differently than Outlook 2013.  I figured out how to disable the preview pane, but I cannot figure out how to get rid of the button.  The button obfuscates the filename.  I can't think of a single reason why I would want an email client to obfuscate a filename in the days of rampant spam and malware.

I would like Outlook 2016 to display the entire filename like Outlook 2013 does.  How do I disable this new button thing?  I only found someone [asking for the same thing](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-outlook/outlook-2016-how-to-show-the-full-name-of/e9964256-6e21-40df-aa17-fe0ffda1a83b) (an [here](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows/suggestions/13466046-display-full-attachment-names-at-the-top-of-the-pr)), no solutions.  Although, it seems that OneNote users have [been complaining](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/327186-onenote-for-windows-windows-phone/suggestions/6933839-show-attachment-file-names-in-full) about this for a while (article says 2012).

As an aside, it seems this is a side effect of the new "[Modern Attachments](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/office-2016-preview-modern-attachments-outlook/)".

Comment: Maybe include a picture of your problem as it would make it more clear. An article that has useful information would be way better than just some posts that also complain. [This](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/outlook-2016-attachment-appearance/fcef7bd3-bb12-4f30-83af-9232d9c6ce81) looks like it might be related (and also shows one way to view the full filename)?